# Botão Excluir com modal mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

Sou iniciante e estou com um problema em um botão (excluir com modal). 
Ao clicar no botão, o sistema deve exibir o modal e se eu clicar em "sim", deve excluir o registro.

Estou mantendo meus códigos em uma página só: "detalhesTarefas.php".

Código do botão:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="direita" style="padding-right:30px;">
    <a href="#excluir" data-uk-modal >
    <div class="btn_all2" type="submit" id='btnApagar' style="margin-left:15px; background-color:#ff0000;">
                EXCLUIR </div> </a>
</form>
```

Código do modal:

```
<div id="excluir" class="uk-modal" >
<div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <div class="uk-modal-header">Excluir</div>
    Deseja mesmo excluir a tarefa?
    <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
        <a class="uk-button" href="">Não</a>
        <a class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit" name="botaoConfirma" value="true" href="painel_constru.php?constru=tarefas">Sim</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Condição acionada pelo botão:

```
$codigo=$_GET["id"];
if (isset($_POST["btnApagar"])) {

    if (isset($_POST["botaoConfirmar"])) {
        $comandoExcluir = "DELETE FROM tbTarefa WHERE idTarefa =" .$codigo; 
        $resultado = $c ->criarConsulta($comandoExcluir);

        if ($resultado) {
            echo "Removido com sucesso";
        } else{
            echo "Não foi removido";
        }
    }
}
```

Ao clicar no botão o registro não é apagado. 
Estava vendo que isso pode ser feito em ajax, mas não tenho muita prática ainda e gostaria também de saber se é possível fazer funcionar dessa forma. Desde já obrigado.

Método de criar a consulta:

```
public function criarConsulta ($sql)
{
     $this->conectarBd();
     $this->comandoSql = $sql; 
     // $result= mysqli_query($con,$comandoSql);
     if ($this->result =mysqli_query($this->con,$this->comandoSql)) {
         $this->desconectarBd();
         return $this->result;
     } else {
       echo "Nao foi possivel realizar comando sql";
       die();
       $this->desconectarBd();
     }
}
```

Comment: Poste o código de criarConsulta()

Comment: <code>public function criarConsulta($sql)
 {
        
   $this->conectarBd();
   $this->comandoSql=$sql;
   
   // $result= mysqli_query($con,$comandoSql);
   if($this->result =mysqli_query($this->con,$this->comandoSql))
    {
     $this->desconectarBd(); 
     return $this->result;
   
     
    }
    else
    {
   echo "Nao foi possivel realizar comando sql";
   die();
   $this->desconectarBd();  
     
    }
  
  
 } </code>

Comment: Observação: Além do problema apresentado, também há risco de [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) em seu código. Para evitar o risco, trate a entrada de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o modal, você deve pensar em front-end primeiro, a parte back-end deve ser pensada posteriormente:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="status" class="alert"></div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Detalhes</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Ação</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- start: Table Body -->
    <tbody>
        <tr class="btnDelete" data-id="1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href="#">Título x</a></td>
            <td>Blá blá blá</td>
            <td>Ativo</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete" href="">Apagar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="btnDelete" data-id="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href="#">Título y</a></td>
            <td>Blá blá blá</td>
            <td>Ativo</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete" href="">Apagar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--/table-collapse -->
<!-- start: Delete Coupon Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Exclusão de registro</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <h4> Você gostaria de deletar este item?</h4>

            </div>
            <!--/modal-body-collapse -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDelteYes" href="#">Sim</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
            </div>
            <!--/modal-footer-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('button.btnDelete').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
   //aqui passamos a ID do registro para dentro do modal, atraveś do click do botão...
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
});

$('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
    var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
    $('[data-id=' + id + ']').remove();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Aqui um exemplo em [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cawscabh/).

Agora vamos passar a ação para o back-end, para que a exclusão seja atendida no PHP.
Primeiramente alteramos o método para que ele permita fazer um post via ajax:

```
$(function() {
  $('#status').hide();
});
$('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
    var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
    $.post('detalhesTarefas.php',{acao:'delete',id:id},function(r) { 
       var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);
       if (m.success) {
        $('[data-id=' + id + ']').remove();
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('#status').removeClass('alert-danger')
                    .addClass('alert-success')
                    .text(m.msg).fadeIn('slow');
       } else {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('#status').removeClass('alert-success')
                    .addClass('alert-danger')
                    .text(m.msg).fadeIn('slow');
       }
          hideMessage();
    }
});

function hideMessage() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#status').hide();
    }, 4000);
}
```

No php, já que você está usando tudo num único arquivo, é importante que esse código seja colocado no início dele e que esse arquivo não contenha código html junto à sua saída, pois JSON deverá ser sua única saída de resposta, para isso utilizarei o **die()**, para interromper qualquer execução que vir abaixo desta ação, para que ele entenda que somente nesta condicão ele deva ser atendido, coloquei uma entrada POST chamada "acao", que será quem irá dizer para o back-end,em que parte do seu arquivo ele irá atender a resposta. Seu arquivo php deverá receber assim:

```
<?php //primeira linha do arquivo php
if ($_POST) {
    $data = array('success' => '0',
                  'msg' => 'Ocorreu um erro, nada foi excluído!');
        $id = (int) $_POST['id'];
        if ($_POST['acao'] == 'delete' && is_int($id)) {
            $comandoExcluir = "DELETE FROM tbTarefa WHERE idTarefa =" .$id; 
            $resultado = $c ->criarConsulta($comandoExcluir);
            if ($resultado) {
               $data = array('success' => '1',
                             'msg' => 'Registro excluído com sucesso!');
            } 
        }
   echo json_encode($data);
   die();
}
//aqui abaixo virá o resto do seu código, html etc....
?>
```

Comment: Muito bom, perfeito e completo.